# oracle - forms : how display narrow field's contents without use tooltip / hint?

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a narrow field i cannot stretch the field or use tooltip/hint (it's not available) , I think about **edit text item** but I want just display without give the ability to change. Do you have a solution?

========================================================================

Answer (score 0):

Keep Field property as per following;

```
Item Type=Text Item
```

under Database make 'No' to Insert allowed and update allowed

--
Kaushik